# The difference between nscd and sssd

Tags: linux, rhel

Quite confused over the difference between Linux Name Service Caching Daemon (NSCD) and System Security Service Daemon ([SSSD](https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/)). As far as I understand, both are used to cache authentication lookup information on the local machine, and still it seems both can be used on the same machine.

What are the differences between the two, and in which cases should I use both ?

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/usingnscd-sssd.html

Comment: `nscd` came from Solaris.  `sssd` is RedHat's re-invention of `nscd` under NIH constraints.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `nscd` is a daemon that provides a cache for the most common name service requests like *passwd*, *group*, *hosts*, *service* and *netgroup*.

`sssd` primarily provides daemons to manage access to remote directories and authentication mechanisms like LDAP, Kerberos, NIS, etc...so it is more about authentication and authorization. It does have its own caching mechanism e.g. for users and groups but there are some more. Consult the manpage of `sssd.conf` for further details.

As in the linked article explained, `sssd` and `nscd` should not be used at the same time as it can result in unexpected lookups. If you need `nscd` e.g. for caching *hosts* entry, which `sssd` does not cache, it is recommended to configure `nscd` only for *hosts* and rely on *user*, *group*, etc. caching on `sssd`.

I think the cases you need to run both services are very rare, since the *hosts* caching is the only entry that `sssd` does not cache.

Comment: Worth noting, Fedora 34 is going [to deprecate nscd in preference of systemd-resolved + sssd](https://pagure.io/fesco/issue/2501), and to remove in 35 release. TL;DR of the change proposal reasoning is: nscd got technical debt and is not actively maintained.